# Restricting symbols to local scope for linux executable

Tags: linux, linker, symbols

Can anyone please suggest some way we can restrict exporting of our symbols to global symbol table?

Thanks in advance

---

Hi,

Thanks for replying...

Actually I have an executable which is statically linked to a  third party library say "ver1.a" and also uses a third party ".so"  file which is again linked with same  library but different version say "ver2.a". Problem is implementation of both these versions is different. At the beginning, when executable is loaded, symbols from "ver1.a" will get exported to global symbol table. Now whenever ".so" is loaded it will try to refer to symbols from ver2.a, it will end up referring to symbols from "ver1.a" which were previously loaded.Thus crashing our binary.

we thought of a solution that we wont be exporting the symbols for executable to Global symbol table, thus when ".so" gets loaded and will try to use symbols from ver2.a it wont find it in global symbol table and it will use its own symbols i.e symbols from ver2.a

I cant find any way by which i can restrict exporting of symbols to global symbol table. I tried with --version-script and retain-symbol-file, but it didn't work. For -fvisibility=hidden option, its giving an error that " -f option may only be used with -shared". So I guess, this too like "--version-script" works only for shared libraries not for executable binaries.

code is in c++, OS-Linux, gcc version-3.2. It may not be possible to recompile any of the third party libraries and ".so"s. So option of recompiling "so' file with bsymbolic flag is ruled out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could at the very least tell us in which language this application is written?

Answer (score 2):

Pull in the 3rd party library with dlopen.

You might be able to avoid that by creating your own shared lib that hides all the third party symbols and only exposes your own API to them, but if all else fails dlopen gives you complete control.

Answer (score 1):

I had, what sounds like, a similar issue/question:  [Segfault on C++ Plugin Library with Duplicate Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821153/segfault-on-c-plugin-library-with-duplicate-symbols)

If you can rebuild the 3rd party library, you could try adding the linker flag `-Bsymbolic` (the flag to gcc/g++ would be `-Wl,-Bsymbolic`).  That might solve your issue.  It all depends on the organization of your code and stuff, as there are caveats to using it:
http://www.technovelty.org/code/c/bsymbolic.html
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-bsymbolic-can-cause-dangerous-side-effects/

If you can't rebuild it, according to the first caveat link:

> In fact, the only thing the -Bsymbolic
>   flag does when building a shared
>   library is add a flag in the dynamic
>   section of the binary called
>   DT_SYMBOLIC.

So maybe there's a way to add the `DT_SYMBOLIC` flag to the dynamic section post-linking?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to rename the symbols (by changing source code) in your executable so they don't conflict with the shared library in the first place.

The next simplest thing is to localize the "problem" symbols with `'objcopy -L problem_symbol'`.

Finally, if you don't link directly with the third party library (but dlopen it instead, as bmargulies suggests), *and* none of your other shared libraries use of define the "problem" symbol, *and* you don't link with -rdynamic or one of its equivalents, then the symbol should not be exported to the *dynamic* symbol table of the executable, and thus you shouldn't have a conflict.

Note: `'nm a.out'` will *still*, show the symbol as globally defined, but that doesn't matter for dynamic linking. You want to look at the *dynamic* symbol table of `a.out` with `'nm -D a.out'`.