# solaris elfedit: Is there something similar for linux ? (a shared library editor)?

Tags: linux, g++, shared-libraries, ld, binutils

Linux: It there a way to edit a compiled shared library ?

specifically I am searching on how to  add the `DT_SYMBOLIC flag` on an already compiled binary shared library?

**Here is why I am asking this**:

our application is composed of

- our own libraries (**static** libXXX.a)
- some 3rd party libs (**binary-only shared** libraries libYYY.so)

Everything is fine with the application so far.

Now I have replaced our own **static*** libXXX.a libraries with shared libraries versions (libXXX.so).

Everything compiles and links fine.

But when I run the application now it starts up and does a lot of expected processing - and then it crashes somewhere on half the way. A gdb backtrace shows that the crash occurs in some of the 3rd party shared libraries.

I searched around on SOF and found an interesting article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804622/restricting-symbols-to-local-scope-for-linux-executable/1848161#1848161).

The tip I am referring to is

```
... add the DT_SYMBOLIC flag to the dynamic section ...
```

Although I doubt that it would really help I think it might be worth a try.

Any ideas how I can add the `DT_SYMBOLIC flag` on an already compiled/linked shared library ?

**environment**: debian lenny 64bit with g++ v4.2.4 and binutils v20.

**EDIT**: on solaris there is a program called `elfedit`. Is there something similar for linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

meanwhile l have found a tool called `elfsh`. It is an interactive shell for examining and editing ELF objects, binaries and shared libraries.

see here for the project page: http://www.eresi-project.org

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be very stable. I have experienced a lot of crashes within `elfsh` itself.

Comment: Is there *any* documentation for `elfsh`? It seems like a great tool except that it's completely undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a flag the painful approach is to tweak your elf header with a hex editor.

But if the 3rd party lib is crashing I'd personally look at the other end of things: what has changed about the library loading order because of you moving to shared.

> ldd

and

> export LD_DEBUG=libs

are your friends here.

dlopen()ing your shared libs after the runtime loader loads your 3rd party libs might be enough.

Comment: Thanks for advice regarding library loading order. But I fear that I have to use the 'painful approach' you mentioned. Any help on how to edit an elf header is very appreciated!

Comment: Again, I can't really recommend this approach, but if I had to I would:
1. read the ELF spec
2. build a minimal library with and without -Bsymbolic and check the binary diff

Comment: "... can't really recommend this approach ...". I agree. But still might be worth a try.